# R plotting a boxplot inside a function does not correctly display y data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes with the same columns. One is historical data and the other is current data. I want to compare a few of the columns using a boxplot for each of them, in order to validate the data.

I created a function to do so.
Inside, it loops through each column I want to plot, transforms the data and plots it. My problem is that my plot does not correctly display the data, even through the dataframe does.

```
reviewPlots <- function(dataset, spider, cols_to_analyze) {
  # CODE TO GET BOTH DATAFRAMES

  # Loop through all columns to produce a boxplot
  for (col in cols_to_analyze){
      # Cast to numeric
      all_crawls_price <- lapply(all_crawls[grepl("[0-9.]",all_crawls[col][[1]]),col],as.numeric)
      this_crawl_price <- lapply(this_crawl[grepl("[0-9.]",this_crawl[col][[1]]),col],as.numeric)
      # Create dataframe for boxplot
      boxplot_df <- data.frame(all_crawls_price, "crawl" = rep("All crawls",length(all_crawls_price)))
      boxplot_df <- rbind(boxplot_df, data.frame(this_crawl_price, "crawl" = rep("This crawl",length(this_crawl_price))))

      print(str(boxplot_df))

      # data.frame':    11550 obs. of  2 variables:
      # $ price_btc: num  0.001231 0.00323 0.000769 0.021535 0.001536 ...
      # $ crawl    : Factor w/ 2 levels "All crawls","This crawl": 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

      p <- ggplot(boxplot_df, aes(x=as.factor(crawl), y=col)) + 
        geom_boxplot() +
        xlab("Crawl") + ylab("Price")

      plot(p)

      cat ("Press <Enter> to continue"); line <- readline()
  }   

}
```

Here is the plot I get:
[image]

I tried adding `environment = environment()` as an argument to the ggplot function, but that did not work either

Comment: Have you considered replacing `aes(x=as.factor(crawl), y=col)` with `aes(x=as.factor(crawl), y=price_btc)`? Or if `price_btc` happens to be your colname under investigation, the following `aes_string(x="crawl", y=col)`

Comment: Yes, same thing happens.

Comment: Last thing I can think of is: `aes(x=as.factor(crawl), y=as.symbol(col))`, does that work? I don't have your data so I can't try on my own.

Comment: I changed col to colname and it worked. Not sure why, maybe a problem since col is also a function ?

Comment: Ah that is unexpected, I'm not sure why. For future people coming here with similar problems, was it just the variable name or did you also change something else compared to what you've posted?

Comment: Actually, I just realised that it works only when I use y=price_btc, instead of y=col

Comment: It is very likely that teunbrand was correct in suggesting `aes_string(x="crawl", y=col)`.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is changed `aes(x=as.factor(crawl), y=col))`to `aes_string(x="crawl", y=colname))` and it worked correctly.